# Best way to implement complex h-index inside ElasticSearch

Tags: java, python, database, elasticsearch, biopython

Given a vast database with hundreds of millions articles (or researcher papers) with title, abstract, author and citation count, what would be the best way to use elastic search so that it returns top k authors by h-index gave a query in sub-second to answer a question like "who are the top brain cancer researchers?"

I'm trying to solve this with an algorithm with the time and memory complexity for a distributed computing system. Ideally with an elastic search plugin. I know using naive believes it would be something like

Group by author -> sort by citation count -> compute h-index -> resort

With such... the complexity would be O(nlog(n)), and require O(n)memory.

I am looking for O(log(h)) run-time and O(k.h) memory solution (n is number articles, h is the average authors' h-index).